# How do i force shut down my windows lumia phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, reset

alright, here is what's going on. I have a phone that will boot loop into a BSOD when I plug it in, and it won't stay shut off when plugged in.  I need to find a way to make it stay off while it's charging so that I can get enough power to finish the recovery process on my computer. is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

if the battery removable you can use external battery charger to charge the battery and complete your process .

Answer (score 0):

If the battery is removable, you might be able to remove the battery then plugin the phone and boot without the battery in it at all.